# jquery.cycle2.js behaves badly on page reload

Tags: javascript

I use cycle plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/, and it goes bad on page reload. When page is loaded, it works ok (try buttons on right of the slider http://krovli-nw.ru). But refresh page, and it stops items in strange position (However, after you click buttons items re-adjust themselves again). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in Cycle2, but it may work with Cycle.

Try explicitly defining the width of your slides (in CSS for example).  There could be an issue where the first element (the one it determines size off of) does not have any size when the javascript loads on the page.  So if you define the size of your slides in CSS, it will always have the correct size.